# Finding the closest strike to current stock price from an option chain.

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, performanceanalytics

The goal is to find the closest strike price from an option chain. This is as far as I have gotten.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers = c("AAPL", "MSFT", "GS")
price = getQuote(tickers)
chains = lapply(tickers, getOptionChain, exp = "2019-01-25")
calls = lapply(chains, function(x) x$calls)

##I was thinking to use a function such as

which.min(abs(calls - price))
```

However I am not to sure in how to put this into lapply or if there is a better alternative. Price is a data frame and calls is a list. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the corresponding rows we may use

```
Map(function(cl, p) cl[which.min(abs(p - cl$Strike)), ], calls, price$Last)
# [[1]]
#                     Strike Last  Chg  Bid  Ask   Vol   OI
# AAPL190104C00148000    148  0.3 0.21 0.24 0.42 43235 4344
#
# [[2]]
#                     Strike Last Chg  Bid  Ask  Vol   OI
# MSFT190104C00102000    102 0.04   0 0.02 0.09 6397 3250
#
# [[3]]
#                   Strike Last  Chg Bid  Ask  Vol  OI
# GS190104C00175000    175 0.25 0.13   0 0.25 2624 678
```

where

```
price$Last
# [1] 148.26 101.93 175.05
```

In this case `lapply` is not the best option since we have to work with two objects at the same time: `price` and `calls`. In that case `mapply` and `Map` do the job, with `Map` being the same as `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`.

So, we go over both `calls` and `price$Last` simultaneously and apply

```
function(cl, p) cl[which.min(abs(p - cl$Strike)), ]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response and the intuition Julien, this worked just how I wanted it to!!